Generating MA Process in matlab using gaussian nosie
I have an MA process that is:
$x[n] = a * w[n] + b * w[n - 1] + c * w[n - 2]$
Where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $w \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^{2})$
How can I generate $x[n]$ in Matlab ?
I know that the code for generating $w[n]$ is:
N = 1e3;
variance = 0.7;

w = randn(1, N) .* variance;

Do I need to pad $w[n]$ with zeros at the start for past samples $w[n - 1]$ and $w[n - 2]$ or are those future samples of $w[n]$ for every sample of $x[n]$ ?
Note: We can assume that $w[n] = 0, n = -1, -2, ... ,  -\infty$

Without any further context, we cannot decide on how $x(0)$ and $x(1)$ should be defined. The most common way would be to define
$$x(0)=aw(0)\text{ and }x(1)=aw(1)+bw(0)$$
You might need to initialize your code with the above formula, and to use a for loop to generate $x$ from $w$.

Given that the past samples of $w[n]$ are zeros so I can just pad my w vector with 2 zeros at the start and then compute the vector x with w ? Beacuse I didn't know if $w[n-1]$ and $w[n-2]$ are the past samples or the future samples of $w[n]$. So from your answer I can see that the correct answer is past samples that need to be initialized.

Correct
w = normrnd(0, sqrt(variance), [N, 1]);
